# deleting from MongoDB gives java.net.SocketException

Tags: android, mongodb

I am trying to delete a document from MongoDB through my Androiod application. I have written this code (given below) for doing that, but this code throws an exception `java.net.SocketException`. So kindly tell how can I delete a document from my database?

**Code:**

```
package com.example.abc.mongo2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        deleteMongo();
    }

    public void deleteMongo() {
        try {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("www.mlab.com",80);
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("my_database");
            boolean auth = db.authenticate("my_username", "my_password".toCharArray());
            DBCollection table = db.getCollection("table");
            BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            searchQuery.put("name", "xyz");
            table.remove(searchQuery);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR","MongoDB", e);
        }
    }


}
```

**Exception**

```
05-15 07:23:07.642 14060-14060/com.example.abc.mongo2 W/org.bson.ObjectId: null
                                                                                     java.net.SocketException
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.rethrowAsSocketException(NetworkInterface.java:225)
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:191)
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.getByName(NetworkInterface.java:118)
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfacesList(NetworkInterface.java:284)
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:275)
                                                                                         at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:579)
                                                                                         at com.mongodb.Bytes.<clinit>(Bytes.java:219)
                                                                                         at com.mongodb.Mongo.<clinit>(Mongo.java:74)
                                                                                         at com.example.abc.mongo2.MainActivity.deleteMongo(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                                         at com.example.abc.mongo2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                      Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                                                                                         at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
                                                                                         at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.collectIpv4Address(NetworkInterface.java:176)
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.getByName(NetworkInterface.java:118) 
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfacesList(NetworkInterface.java:284) 
                                                                                         at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:275) 
                                                                                         at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:579) 
                                                                                         at com.mongodb.Bytes.<clinit>(Bytes.java:219) 
                                                                                         at com.mongodb.Mongo.<clinit>(Mongo.java:74) 
                                                                                         at com.example.abc.mongo2.MainActivity.deleteMongo(MainActivity.java:27) 
                                                                                         at com.example.abc.mongo2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```